# How would this Fortran conditional expression evaluate?

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran95

In the Fortran95 code below the variable NMOM is an integer and always equal to 3.

What would the value of P0 evaluate to, 1 or -1?  The divide by 2 then multiply by 2 bit has me confused, I'm not sure why you would do this, but this was written by a non-programmer scientist back in the 90s who is no longer around to ask.

```
P0=1
IF(NMOM-NMOM/2*2.EQ.1)P0=-1
```

The code is compiled with lf95 on a Linux machine.

Comment: IMO, if the program works (meaning it does what it's supposed to do and gives correct results) then the scientist *is* a programmer. He/she may not be a *good* programmer (who can optimize or comment well), but they would most certainly be a programmer.

Comment: If it's Fortran 95, it's definitely not ancient code. That's practically modern in Fortran terms. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Fortran, but my guess is that it is testing if NMOM is odd or even. First, rewrite with parens to simulate operator precedence:

```
IF(NMOM-((NMOM/2)*2).EQ.1)P0=-1
```

And if we are using integer math then (NMOM/2)*2 == NMOM if it's even else it will equal NMOM-1 if it's odd.

Comment: The integer arithmetic is what's interesting here, in that the divide by 2 will give only the integer part of the result, it all makes sense now, thanks for your help!